# ¿Cómo puedo insertar en una tabla varios datos en un campo MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

```
     $query = mysqli_query($conect,'SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE 
     id='.$_SESSION['producto'][$i].'');

         for ($j=0; $j < $_SESSION['contador2']; $j++){

            $cab =  $_SESSION['cantidad'][$i];

   while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $filaid = $fila['id'];
            $noma = $fila['Nombre'];
            $totalpeso = $fila['peso']*$cab;
            $total = $fila['Precio']*$cab;
            $totalproductosvendi = $fila['Cantidad']-$cab;

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$fila['Nombre'].'</td>';
            echo'<td></td>';
            echo '<center><td>';
            echo '<center><input type="number" name="ja" class="la" 
       value="'.$cab.'""></center>';
            echo '</td></center>';
            echo '<td>$'.$fila['Precio'].'</td>';
            echo '<td><input type=hidden value='.$fila['peso'].'</td>';
            echo '<td><input type=hidden 
       value='.$fila['Cantidad'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>$'.number_format($total,2).'</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            //echo $totalpeso;
            //echo '<a href=functions/check3.php?a='.$i.' 
        class=borrar>Borrar</a>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
```

ingreso en la tabla pedido

```
      mysqli_query($conect,"INSERT INTO Pedido 
     (Nombre,Cantidad,Factura,estado) VALUES (('$noma'),('$cab'),
   ('$id'),('$estado'))");
```

solo me ingresa el ultimo producto pero no todos los que etsan en la consulta

Comment: Vas a tener que mejorar la pregunta. De todos modos creo que el problema que tienes es de diseño de la base de datos, ¿lo que quieres, es tener en un registro de "factura" el nombre de varios productos?

Comment: si osea hago una consulta en una tabla y en otra desdeo ingresar el nombre de lo que salga de la consulta pero ahora solo me ingresa el ultimo nombre y no los 4 que estan

Comment: Tienes que añadir código para que alguien pueda plantearte que corregir. Yo creo que aunque el diseño de la BD esta mal, puedes incluir en  'factura.nombre' un string con x número de 'producto.nombre', para lo que debes componer este string recorriendo los resultados obtenidos de consultar la tabla 'producto', todo esto por código PHP.